# SSRS IIF Date format less than a specified date

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I need to replace a value in one column based on an expression that say IIF its less than this date then say this or false, I know I just have the syntax wrong:

```
=IIF(Fields!DateCol1.Value, < (Format(20140406), "yyyyMMdd") , "Hello" , false)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
=IIF(Fields!DateCol1.Value < CDate("2014-04-06") , "I am less" , "I am greater or equal")
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: @Hudin, If my answer solved your question, you can select it as _correct_ answer. [How to accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: This was my final expression : =IIF(Fields!DateCol1.Value < CDate("2014-04-06") , "Hello" ,Format(Fields!DateCol1.Value, "dd/MM/yy"))

Answer (score 2):

```
=IIF(Fields!DateCol1.Value < CDate("2014-04-06") , "Hello" ,Format(Fields!DateCol1.Value, "dd/MM/yy"))
```